# how can i loop like this but getting everything instead of only the 1st one

Tags: python, dictionary

i want loop like this but getting everything instead of only the 1st one.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

myList = OrderedDict(
                    {
                    'ID': ["1stID", "2ndID","3ndID"], 'ChannelID': ["1stChannel", "2ndChannel","3ndChannel"]
                    })
first_values = [v[0] for v in myList.values()]
print(first_values)

OUTPUT 
['1stID', '1stChannel']
```

instead of

```
['1stID', '1stChannel']
DESIRED OUTPUT:
['1stID', '1stChannel']
['2stID', '2stChannel']
['3stID', '3stChannel']
```

Comment: Clue: Try printing: print(myList.values())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()` to combine two list and get the combined pairs, as follows:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

myList = OrderedDict(
    {
        'ID': ["1stID", "2ndID", "3ndID"],
        'ChannelID': ["1stChannel", "2ndChannel", "3ndChannel"]
    })

pairs = zip(myList['ID'], myList['ChannelID'])
# list(pairs) -> [('1stID', '1stChannel'), ('2ndID', '2ndChannel'), ('3ndID', '3ndChannel')]

for pair in pairs:
    print(list(pair))
```

Result:

```
['1stID', '1stChannel']
['2ndID', '2ndChannel']
['3ndID', '3ndChannel']
```

Answer (score 1):

Other method (if you don't want to use key names):

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

myList = OrderedDict(
    {
        "ID": ["1stID", "2ndID", "3ndID"],
        "ChannelID": ["1stChannel", "2ndChannel", "3ndChannel"],
    }
)

for a in zip(*myList.values()):
    print(a)  # or list(a) for lists instead of tuples
```

Prints:

```
('1stID', '1stChannel')
('2ndID', '2ndChannel')
('3ndID', '3ndChannel')
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the structure you are building so you are not accessing it correctly.

mylist is a 2 element dictionary. each of the element are lists of length 3.
There is no connection between the positional elements of each other than the position.

See code below how I extracted and printed the data.
There may be an idiomatic way to do this in python more cleanly
but this served to show the structure clearly.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

myList = OrderedDict(
    {
        'ID': ["1stID", "2ndID", "3ndID"],
        'ChannelID': ["1stChannel", "2ndChannel", "3ndChannel"]
    })
first_values = [v[0] for v in myList.values()]
print(first_values)
#
# print out the values of the objects in the list  

for v in myList.values():
    print(v)

# extract the two lists        
vid, vchan = myList.values()

# print out the whole list in one statement
print("all of vid ", vid)
print("all of vchan ", vchan)

# print out the element of the lists position by position    
for i in range(len(vid)):
    print(i, "th list item ", vid[i], vchan[i])
```